# User is creating when email is in wrong format even though I used the regualr expression validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

I am trying to create a user with the create user wizard. For email validation i am using regualr expression control. I given `ControlToValidate` property to the id of the email text box. When I given wrong email Id and click on create user it is showing error message what i configured in the `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>`but it is going to next step and saying **user created succesfully**.  **How to stop register the user** when email format is wrong. I am trying to modify the `CreatingUser` event like this

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            bool allfieldsstatus = false;
            RegularExpressionValidator emailvalidator = (RegularExpressionValidator)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("emailvalidator");

            if (!emailvalidator.Visible)
            {
                allfieldsstatus = true;
            }

            if (allfieldsstatus)
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

But this is not working. The visibility property not at all showing. I tried in another way in `if` condition as 
`if(!emailvalidator.ErrorMessage.length!=0)
  { 
allfieldstatus = true;
}`
This is also not working. Because the `ErrorMessage` property is always be there in configuration of `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator >`
What is the solution for this?

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="createUseWizard" AutoGeneratePassword="True" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Account/AdminRegister.aspx"
            CreateUserButtonText="Register User" 
            OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" BorderStyle="None" 
            DisplayCancelButton="True" oncreatinguser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser" 
            LoginCreatedUser="False">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="registerUserDiv">
                            <div id="registerUserHeader">
                                Register New User
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="registerUserLable">
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text="User Name" AssociatedControlID="UserName"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inputTextbox">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="showInRed" ID="UserIDrequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                        ErrorMessage="Email is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"
                                        SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="registerUserLable">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="E-mail" AssociatedControlID="Email"></asp:Label></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputTextbox">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="showInRed" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required."
                                    ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="registerUserLable">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="Select Role" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="inputTextbox">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="rolesDropdown" runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="errorEmail">
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailvalidator" runat="server" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Email Should be in correct format" ControlToValidate="Email" 
                                    SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
                                        Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: What regexp do you use to validate email?

Comment: Intenet Email address `ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"`

Comment: Why are you checking whether it's *visible* or not? Surely you should be calling `Validate`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried with the `IsValid` but in that case also not working properly

Comment: @Mihir: You need to give more details - including whether or not you called `Validate` (as I said) or just `IsValid`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't called `Validate` method. In which part of the page I have to call the `validate` method?

Comment: @Mihir: I'm not sure; I'm not an ASP.NET developer. But you should read the Remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx carefully.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should check if validation passed with the `IsValid` property of single validator controls or of the Page itself:

```
if (!emailvalidator.IsValid) {
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

or

```
if (!Page.IsValid) {
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

For the wizard, you could perform this check in the `NextButtonClick` and `FinishButtonClick` event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But for first time it is validating. If i click again create user button now it is not validating. User is creating with that wrong email lid

Comment: I added the above code in the `NextButtonClick` and `FinishButtonClick` events

Comment: @Mihir: you mean the second time the event is executed anyway but `IsValid` is true?

Comment: Yeah... for first time `Isvalid` is false and for second time it is coming as true

Comment: @Mihir: could you post a simplified example that shows this behavior?

Comment: I posted above code right!! that is the only thing where i am handling this. You want me to post the `<asp>` tag for email and `regularexpressionvalidator` also?

Comment: @Mihir: I think it would help, even better if you can post the whole wizard code...

Answer (score 0):

If you think it's RegExp problem try this:

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i
```